# Redirecting Links from root to new Site in Sub-directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, migration

I've recently changed my site over to Wordpress to allow for easier and more intuitive editing but this leaves me with a problem of redirecting links that I know are out there in forum posts and the like as well as linked imagery etc.

I don't really want to remove the old site files just yet, just in case I need something from them but I don't want incoming visitors to see them.

I could go and add redirects to links I can think of to the htaccess file but that would be too time consuming and one of the main reasons to transferring to Wordpress was because the web site had grown to big to do things manually, so there are a lot of potential links.

An example of my old structure was mysite.com/index.html , mysite.com/index_2.php , mysite.com/contact/ etc...

My new site structure is mysite.com/index.html , mysite.com/guests , mysite.com/guests/contact/ etc...

So the new links for everything except the landing page (index.html) and a couple resource directories will be in the guests directory.

Is there any easy (or less time intensive) way of directing traffic in a search engine friendly manner to the guests directory when required yet still allowing access to specific root folders?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this WordPress plugin can help you

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/